# Luacheck include files from exclude directory

Tags: lua, luacheck

I have a project like this (in fact, there are more files and dirs):

```
.
├── src
│   ├── main.lua
│   └── smth.lua
└── tests
    ├── others
    │   ├── others_1.lua
    │   ├── others_2.lua
    │   └── others_3.lua
    ├── speed_tests
    │   ├── test1.lua
    │   └── test2.lua
    └── sql
        ├── join.lua
        └── select.lua
```

and I have such `.luacheckrc`:

```
include_files = {
    "**/*.lua"
}

exclude_files = {
    "tests/**/*.lua",
}
```

I want `luacheck` utility to check files in `tests/sql` directory, but not to touch other directories in `tests/`. Of course, I can explicitly write:

```
exclude_files = {
    "tests/others/*.lua",
    "tests/speed_tests/*.lua"
}
```

, but in real project there're 15+ dirs and it doesn't look good to do that.

How can I reach a goal elegantly?

Comment: so you want to exclude a specific folder but you don't want to explicitly name it? how is luacheck supposed to know it then?

Comment: no, if you are talking about `include_file { "tests/sql/*.lua}`, it will not work because files from this folder will match the pattern "tests/**/*.lua" in `exclude_file`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use exclude then, only include dirs you wish to traverse.

```
include_files = {
    "src/*.lua",
    "tests/sql/*.lua"
}
```